# How to connect to RDS from local JAVA program via EC2 SSH tunnel

Tags: java, mysql, ssh, amazon-rds, jsch

I'm trying to connect to the RDS database from a local JAVA program via SSH tunnel to an EC2 instance for debugging purposes. I'm trying to do a SSH tunnel into an EC2 instance, then port forwarding to the RDS database. Here's my code.

```
final int localPort = 9999;
// Create BaiscDataSource.
final String databaseURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:" + localPort + "/database";
// SSH Tunnel.
final JSch jsch = new JSch();
jsch.addIdentity(sshKeyPath);
this.session = jsch.getSession(ec2Username, ec2Host, 22);
this.session.setTimeout(0);
this.session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
this.session.connect();
this.session.setPortForwardingL(localPort, rdsHost, 3306);
```

Please help!

Edited by: looply_dev on Oct 2, 2012 4:17 PM

Comment: You need to set up tunnel from Java as well? Setting it up just outside of your program and then pointing db URL to `localhost:9999` won't cut it?

Comment: Otherwise here's a working example I used once. http://www.beanizer.org/site/index.php/en/Articles/Java-ssh-tunneling-with-jsch.html You might want to run it in a separate thread, I don't recall whether it's blocking or not.

Comment: I tried both actually. In both cases, executing a query will hang.

Comment: If you set up a tunnel outside of java program and then just simply telnet to that port, do you see mysql spitting out data? I.e. are you sure your tunnel works ok?

Comment: Yes. that does work. so i guess this confirms that the tunnel is good.

Comment: And you checked out the link I pasted? That doesn't work either?

Comment: yup. i checked it out before i posted the question.

Answer (score 1):

I got what your doing to work, but not using the jcraft jsch library. I was able to execute a terminal command from inside my java application on a seperate thread. Here is the terminal command:

```
ssh -i /path/to/pem/ -L -N localport:remotehost:remoteport remoteuser@remotetunnelserver.com
```

And then in your java jdbc adapter code connect on `127.0.0.1` with the localport above:

```
jdbc.mysql://127.0.0.1:1345/databasename/user=user&password=pass
```

The problem i think is -N option in the command creates a tunnel only with an innability to execute remote commands thru the tunnel, which is true by default in the jsch libraray of jcraft and I am unable to set the default to false fro executing remote commands.

Comment: `jdbc.mysql://127.0.0.1:1345/databasename/user=user&password=pass' is  not correct`. The `jdbc` part must be followed by a `:`

Answer (score 1):

I used a Bastion host and used local port forwarding.

```
ssh -i ec2key.pem -N -L 3306:my-dev-db.cluster-cdnxxxxxxxxxx.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 ec2-user@54.253.196.193
```

***54.253.196.193*** is the IP of the bastian host.

Finally, I connected to the localhost:3306 using AWS Secrets Manager. But you should also be able to use database username and password as well.